# C# Regex Validating Mac Address

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to validate mac addresses. In this instance there is no `-` or `:` for example a valid mac would be either:

```
0000000000
00-00-00-00-00-00
00:00:00:00:00:00
```

However I keep getting false when run against the below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace parsingxml
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Give me a mac address: ");

            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            input = input.Replace(" ", "").Replace(":","").Replace("-","");

            Regex r = new Regex("^([:xdigit:]){12}$");


            if (r.IsMatch(input))
            {
                Console.Write("Valid Mac");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Invalid Mac");
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT: Invalid Mac

Comment: Uh what is `[:xdigit:]`?

Comment: Not in .NET it's not.

Comment: See my edit below. Your code works for me if I put in my Regex string.

Comment: My sample code is too long, I've posted it on MSDN : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6f8b4ca-f0d3-4597-9dea-ebf7e73c5ce4/mac-address-validation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[.NET regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx) ***does not have support for POSIX character class***. And even if it does support, you need to enclose it in `[]` to make it effective, i.e. `[[:xdigit:]]`, otherwise, it will be treated as a character class with the characters `:`, `x`, `d`, `i`, `g`, `t`.

You probably want this regex instead (for the MAC address after you have cleaned up the unwanted characters):

```
^[a-fA-F0-9]{12}$
```

Note that by cleaning up the string of space, `-` and `:`, you will allow inputs as shown below to pass:

```
   34:   3-342-9fbc: 6:7
```

[**DEMO**](https://ideone.com/P7s2Yw)

Comment: Will not match `12-23-34-45-56-67` or `12:23:34:45:56:67` which are valid according to the asker.

Comment: @SpikeX: **Read the code** - OP has cleaned up the characters `:` and `-`. So they will match.

Comment: Perhaps OP only cleaned up the characters because he thought that was the only way to validate it. @ZacBorders If your input really only does have letters and numbers in it (no `:` or `-`), then this should definitely work for you: `^[a-fA-F0-9]{12}$`. If it doesn't, you're doing something else wrong and you should debug your program to find out what it is.

Comment: @ZacBorders: See the demo.

Comment: @SpikeX When debugging with or without - or : input shows proper, as in 000000000000 when it is passed to r.ismatch

Comment: I believe this is the best answer so far, considering that the OP cleans up the characters `:`, `-` and space (but I do think that he shouldn't be doing it)

Comment: Best Answer, I must have misstyped when I tried [a-fA-F0-9]{12}$

Answer (score 5):

Try this regex instead:

`^(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}-){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2}$`

Matches:

- 12-23-34-45-56-67
- 12:23:34:45:56:67
- 122334455667

But not:

- 12:34-4556-67

---

Edit: Your code works for me.

[image]

Comment: I don't doubt that works but I'm more curious as to why my implementation fails as theoretically it would match even 12:34-4556-67 and I don't want to be hung up on the poor typing skills of the user giving me the mac.

Comment: You should only accept valid MAC addresses in the format defined by the IEEE MAC-48 standard: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_Address As such, `12:23-3445-56:67` is **not** valid.

Comment: @ZacBorders: The problem is that the regex you wrote is not supported by .NET regex. The idea is correct, though.

Comment: @SpikeX: I think it is fair to clean up (reformat) the input, show to the user, and validate it.

Comment: @SpikeX I agree with you if it wasn't any more than needing to strip out the characters to search for files with the mac addy in the filename anyways. Much appreciated however.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could just do this:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^([0-9a-fA-F]{2}(?:(?:-[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){5}|(?::[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{10}))$");
```

Or this, which is a lot simpler and would be a little more forgiving:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^([0-9a-fA-F]{2}(?:[:-]?[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){5})$");
```

Comment: This doesn't match any of `122334455667`, `12-23-34-45-56-67`, or `12:23:34:45:56:67`. http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: And now your regex isn't even valid, you have an unmatched parenthesis.

Comment: @SpikeX Took me a little while to be able to test it. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

```
        using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
        try{
            PhysicalAddress py = PhysicalAddress.Parse("abcd");
        }catch(Exception){
            Console.WriteLine("Mac address not valid");
        }
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: The question is about a regex solution

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a regular expression like this one, myself:

```
Regex rxMacAddress = new Regex( @"^[0-9a-fA-F]{2}(((:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){5})|((:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){5}))$") ;
```

6 pairs of hex digits, separator either by colons or by hyphens, but not a mixture.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. There is a small mistake though I believe: the second : should be a -

Answer (score 0):

Your regex isn't good. Here you got a good one:

```
public const string ValidatorInvalidMacAddress = "^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]?){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$";
```

Comment: Simply posting the regex is not going to help Zac learn why his regex needs work. The answer should be improved to explain why his regex need improvement and give readers an understanding of what the proposed regex is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Regex expression that worked for me and accept either macaddress with either all - or all : separation is :- "^[0-9a-fA-F]{2}(((:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){5})|((-[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){5}))$"